# Is my pumping lemma proof correct?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

> Show that $L = \{a^nb^l \ | \ n \leq l \}$ is not regular

I'd like to check if my proof for this is correct.

*Proof:* Choose any positive integer $m$. Pick $w = a^mb^{m+1} \in L$. Note that $|w| = 2m+1 \geq m$ and $1\leq |a^m| \leq m$. Write $w=xyz$ where $x=\varepsilon$, $y=a^m$ and $z=b^{m+1}$. We have
$$xy^3z= \varepsilon(a^m)^3b^{m+1} = a^{3m}b^{m+1} \not\in L\,,$$
since $3m > m+1$ for any positive integer $m$. Thus by the contrapositive of the Pumping Lemma we can conclude that $L$ is not regular. $\square$

---

<sub>Although we normally close "check my work questions", this question illustrates a very common mistake with the pumping lemma, so is intended as a reference question.</sub>

Comment: I edited the proof slightly to turn this into a reference question because you've made a common and instructive mistake. You also did some slightly strange stuff observing that $\varepsilon=a^0b^0\in L$ which is true but not relevant. Nothing in the pumping lemma requires that $x\in L$, so I removed that part.

Comment: Doh! I did the exact same thing with a different "[is my pumping lemma proof correct?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/44994/9550)" question three years ago, and wrote an almost identical answer! So this should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

No, this proof is not correct.

To prove that a language is non-regular using the pumping lemma, you need to show that:

1. for all $m>0$, there is a string $w\in L$ of length at least $m$ such that
2. for all ways of writing $w=xyz$ with $|y|\geq 1$,
3. there is some $i\geq 0$ such that $xy^iz\notin L$.

You have shown that *some* way of writing $w=xyz$ makes part 3 true, but that is not enough.

To understand why, it's helpful to consider why the pumping lemma is true. The point is that, if a language is regular, it is accepted by a DFA and that DFA has some number $n$ of states. That means that, if it reads a string $w$ of length more than $n$ then, by the pigeonhole principle, it must enter some state $q$ twice (or more).  Then we can set $w=xyz$ where

- $x$ is what is read before entering $q$ for the first time ($x=\varepsilon$ if $q$ is the initial state);
- $y$ is what is read after the character that causes the first entry to $q$ up to, but not including, the character that causes the second entry to $q$ (so $y$ contains at least one character, i.e., $|y|\geq 1$);
- $z$ is the rest of the string.

Now the point is that the string $xy^iz$ causes the DFA to go around the loop from $q$ to $q$ $i$ times, then carry on to an accepting state by reading $z$, so every string $xy^iz$ must also be accepted. However, the specific partition of $w$ into $x$, $y$ and $z$ depends on which automaton you're considering. To show that *no* automaton accepts the language, you need to show that every possible automaton fails, which means you need to show that all possible partitions $w=xyz$ fail.